# What is the difference between designing an algorithm that solves a problem and creating a TM that decides a language?

Tags: algorithm-analysis

Question: What is the difference between designing an algorithm that solves a problem and creating a Turing machine that decides a language?

A turing machine "decides" the language if it "accepts" the language and enters a rejecting state for any input not in the language.

Don't really know what the difference is

Comment: There is no real difference.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the problem, there might not be any difference.

If the problem's goal is to answer a yes/no question, then there is no difference; accepting the input is equivalent to answering yes, and rejecting is equivalent to answering no.

However, if the goal of your problem is to output something else (e.g., output a number), then it is not identical to deciding a language.  There are still ways to formulate a corresponding language, but the correspondence is not quite as direct.

To learn more, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_problem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_problem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language.